# is there a probability of thread unsafety in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, concurrency

```js
let arr = [2, 3]

let promiseA = new Promise((resolve)=>{
    // await for io
    resolve(arr.shift())
})
let promiseB = new Promise((resolve)=>{
    // await for io
    resolve(arr.shift())
})
let handler = (data)=>{
    if(!data){
        return console.log("no more")
    }
    console.log(data)
}
promiseA.then(handler)
promiseB.then(handler)
```

Hello, I have a question about concurrence in javascript.

If `promiseA` and `promiseB` will be resolved one by one, there will be no problem then.

But, if the the two io operations take the same time, is there a chance that both `promiseA` and `promiseB` will be resolved with the value `2`?

Comment: JavaScript is not a concurrent language. The programming model is single-threaded. One Promise will resolve before the other, so there's that, but that's not really a *concurrency* problem, it's a *synchronization* problem. The bottom line is that writing code like that would probably be a bad idea.

Comment: There is a possibility that the output would be `3` then `2`. There is no possibility it would be `2` then `2`.

Comment: Make your question more interesting...next time use Web Workers and create multiple processes and ask the same question. Of course the answer is still the same as Pointy stated, but would be a much more fun question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy (in the comments) is correct, but just to formalize it:

---

### Promise body, messages, and the event loop

Any code that runs in the body of the two `Promises` will execute as messages in the main JavaScript [Event Loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop).

JavaScript runs one message at a time and once a message is running in the main event loop it will [run to completion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Run-to-completion) before anything else happens:

> ...it cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs (and can modify data the function manipulates).

Calls like `setTimeout` queue `messages` for the main event loop, so the work done in the body of the two `Promises` may span multiple messages, but each message is run one at a time and run to completion before anything else runs.

So at the time that each promise body reaches this line:

```
resolve(arr.shift())
```

...it will be the currently running message and "cannot be pre-empted and will run entirely before any other code runs".

---

### Promise callbacks and the PromiseJobs queue

When a `Promise` resolves, any callbacks waiting on the `Promise` get queued in the [PromiseJobs queue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues) which is a special Job Queue introduced with ES6.

Callbacks in the PromiseJobs queue run *after the current message completes and before the next message begins* and run one at a time, in order, until the queue is empty.

---

### So...is there a chance that both promiseA and promiseB will be resolved with the value 2?

No.  There is a zero chance that both `Promises` will resolve with the value `2`.

This line:

```
resolve(arr.shift())
```

...is synchronous and the array operation and `resolve` will both run to completion as part of the currently running message before any other code runs.

This means that each `handler` callback is guaranteed to be queued in PromiseJobs with a unique value.

---

**Bonus**

The way the code is written, `handler` is guaranteed to be queued in PromiseJobs with `2` first, and then to be queued in PromiseJobs with `3` afterwards, *regardless of which `Promise` resolves first*, so the `handler` callbacks are guaranteed to run in that order and the above code will **always** print `2` before it prints `3`.